# How can I run ansible playbook for localhost to add key having passphrase to ssh-add?

Tags: bash, ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

- I want to run an ansible playbook that will run on localhost.
- SSH Passphrase is stored in a variable (say `"{{ sshpassphrase }}"`)
- Probably, the playbook will run some script/code (bash/python/similar) that will check `ssh-agent` is running or not. Then using `ssh-add PATH`, it will add the key with the help of passphrase.

Is that possible? Any how-to?

I started with a sample bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps_out=`ps -U "$USER" | grep ssh-agent | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v $0`
result=$(echo $ps_out | grep ssh-agent)
if [[ "$result" != "" ]];then
    echo "ssh-agent running"
else
    echo "ssh-agent not running, starting"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
fi

ssh-add ~/.ssh/"$1"
```

Ansible Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - ../inventories/group_vars/vars.yml
  pre_tasks:
    -name: Add sshkey having passphrase to agent
     ansible.builtin.shell: |
       ps_out=`ps -U "$USER" | grep ssh-agent | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v $0`
       result=$(echo $ps_out | grep ssh-agent)
       if [[ "$result" != "" ]];then
         echo "ssh-agent running"
       else
         echo "ssh-agent not running, starting"
         eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
       fi

       expect << EOF
         spawn ssh-add ~/.ssh/{{ keyfilename }}
         expect "Enter passphrase"
         send "{{ sshpassphrase }}"
         expect of
       EOF

       exit 0
     delegate_to: localhost
...
```

Also don't want the passphrase to be in terminal/bash history.

The above playbook does not add any agent (checked after running the playbook using `ssh-add -l`).

Comment: What is the error or undesirable behavior you get with the above code?

Comment: FWIW. See [Run Ansible playbooks in cron](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example1-cron.html). A wrapper prepares the environment and uses *ansible-runner* to execute a playbook.

Comment: There are 2 problems related to the fact that ansible spawns a new connection on every command and does not read shell initialization file. 1) when your agent is running, you don't have the related environment variables available in the current shell: `ssh-add` will fail since it does not have the agent PID nor socket. 2) when your agent is not running, your task will start a new one and register the vars in the current shell. But the agent will die as soon as the task is over and the vars will not survive either. I suspect you're in an x/y problem and actually looking for ssh-agent forwarding

Comment: A way to do similar is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76195643/4464045).